# Login with facebook error, codeigniter invalid url

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I am working on a project. I want the user login with facebook. But after the facebook authentication, I get this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a sub-domain of one of the App's domains.

I searched on Google for a long time and everytime I get this answer that there may be a problem in my facebook application domain name.

I changed my fb application again and again but everytime I get the same error.

Some settings of my facebook application are:

> App Domains:     superhitdomains.com
>   
>   Site URL:        http://superhitdomains.com
>   
>   My view page is :

[Login with facebook](http://superhitdomains.com/social/fb_request)

and my controller is:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Social extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
        $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
        $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);
    }

    public function fb_request()
    {
       $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
       if($userId == 0)
       {
          $data = array(
            'redirect_uri'=> base_url().'social/handle_user_fb_login',
            'scope'=>'email'
          );
          redirect($this->facebook->getLoginUrl($data));
          //print_r($data); exit;
       }
       else 
       {
         // Get user's data and print it
         $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
         print_r($user);    
       }
    }

    public function handle_user_fb_login()
    {
        $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
        if($userId !=0)
        {
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            print_r($user); 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'could not connected with facebook';
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: i think your app settings is not correct

Comment: so what should be wrong in my app ? I have followd a lot of tutorials for creating app and there is only two things that have to correct. one is app domains which in my case superhitdomains.com and the other is site url which is http://superhitdomains.com. What do you think what will be wrong in my app setting ?? Thanks

Comment: have you added http:// before site utl in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to asume that your `base_url().'social/handle_user_fb_login'` is an invalid url to redirect the user with. Check your Facebook app and make sure that `base_url()` indeed is mentioned as either canvas url or website url.

This is something Facebook enforces so that their own site can redirect you accordingly and not directly send you to (others) malicious sites.

Comment: I changed the domain name and site url in my application again and again,the user is authenticated by the facebook but after authentication, I am getting this error.

Comment: I still believe that it's due to your `'redirect_uri'` value.